# How to add even element of list in a line without commas

Tags: python, list

I have the following file :

**Rawdata.txt**

```
ID Name
1 XYZ A, B, C
2 XYS D, E, F
3 YWZ G, H, I
4 XWE J, K, L
```

and need to reformat it to following :

**output_data.txt**

```
ID Name X1 Y1 Z1
1 XYZ A, B, C XYZ A  B  C
2 XYS D, E, F XYS D  E  F
3 YWZ G, H, I YWZ G  H  I
4 XWE J, K, L XWE J  K  L
```

I have used following script till now :

```
with open('Rawdata.txt','r') as input_file:
  lines = input_file.read().splitlines()
  lines.pop(0)
  newList = [element for item in lines for element in item.split('\t')]
  #print newList

  with open('output_data.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write("ID\tName\tX1\tY1\tZ1\n")

    for i in range(len(newList)):
       s = "".join(newList[i:(i+1)])

       output_file.write(s)
       output_file.write("\n")
```

Right now my file looks like this :

```
ID Name X1 Y1 Z1
1 XYZ A, B, C 
2 XYS D, E, F 
3 YWZ G, H, I 
4 XWE J, K, L
```

How to add the remaining columns in the output_data file?

Comment: Is this file a csv file? If so please post in valid csv format

Comment: It is tab-delimited text

Comment: @Jaba - no mention of csv in the question

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: Just trying to figure out the before and after and how they coorelate

Comment: @wwii
I could obtain only uptill this :

ID Name X1 Y1 Z1
1 XYZ A, B, C 
2 XYS D, E, F 
3 YWZ G, H, I 
4 XWE J, K, L

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @wwii on same line

Comment: Please have a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u almost got your code right. But I just made small correction in your code which makes it how you want.

```
with open('Rawdata.txt','r') as input_file:
  lines = input_file.read().splitlines()
  lines.pop(0)
  newList = [element for item in lines for element in item.split('\t')]
  print(newList)
  import regex as re
  with open('output_data.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write("ID\tName\tX1\tY1\tZ1\n")

    for i in range(len(newList)):
       s = "\t".join(newList[i:(i+1)])
       s1 = re.sub(r'\d+?',' ',s)
       s1 = re.sub(r'\,',' ',s1)
       s = s+ s1
       output_file.write(s)
       output_file.write("\n")
```

I used regex to detect all integers and replace it with space and used similar case in commas also. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Iterate over each line of the file; left-split the line to get the part you want to duplicate; replace the commas in the new part with a tab(?); join the original line and the new part; write that to the output file.

```
with open('Rawdata.txt','r') as f, open('output_data.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write("ID\tName\tX1\tY1\tZ1\n")
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        _, new = line.lsplit()
        new = new.replace(',', '\t')
        line = '\t'.join([line,new]) + '\n'
        out.write(line)
```